# sql server top query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I don't know what's wrong with this query :

```
select * from products , top 1 * from pic 
where products.productId = pic.productId
```

I have Products and Pic tables , every products could have 1 to n pic and I would like to return every product and the first pic of that

The picture of diagram may help [image]

Comment: What results are you getting? What results are you expecting?

Comment: @Oded , Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'. I wanna return all product with the first pic which is associated with it

Comment: I upvoted a better answer than mine (in my opinion), but now it's disappeared?

Comment: @Dems: Answers does not disappear .. They get temporarely deteted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a way of uniquely identifying each pic, so I'm asuming that table as an ID column...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  products
LEFT JOIN
  pic
    ON pic.Id = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM pic WHERE productID = products.ProductID ORDER BY id DESC)
```

**EDIT**

Inspired by another answer, using APPLY instead...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  products
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM pic WHERE productID = products.ProductID ORDER BY id DESC) AS pic
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery to

- select the first PicID's for each ProductID
- join with Pic table itself to get the additional columns
- join with Products to get the product columns

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Products prod
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Pic p ON p.ProductID = prod.ProductID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT PicID = MIN(PicID)
                 , ProductID
          FROM   Pic
          GROUP BY
                 ProductID
        ) pm ON pm.PicID = p.PicID
```

Comment: If there is a product without picture - your script will not catch it. Change to LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

There is also way with subsection but please avoid sub select  as much as You can in yours TSQL

```
Select 
*
,(select top(1) adress from pic where pic.productid=products.id /* if u wanna you also can order by id */   ) as Id
from products
```